# How expand the domain of the $\log$ function from $\Bbb Z$ to $\Bbb Q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Let function $f(N)=\log N$ while $N \in \Bbb N$

One can expand the domain from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb Z$ by a clear mathematical approach

$$f(N) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \log N & \quad \text{if $N>0 \qquad; N \in \Bbb Z$}\\
    \log N + \Bbb i\pi & \quad \text{if $N<0$}
  \end{array} \right.$$

***Question:*** *Let $f(Q)$ and $Q\in \Bbb Q$, how may I expand the domain from integers $\Bbb Z$ to rationals $\Bbb Q$ through a mathemtically clear approach?*

Comment: is it $f(N)=\log N$? Try not to mess up the case. And why use $Z$ and $\zeta$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry for the confusion. Should work now.

Comment: No, you still define $f(Z)$ in terms of $N$. There is no $N$ in that expression. If you want to us "clear formalisms," you need to be clearer than that.

Comment: I suggest you start by clearly understanding the mathematical definition of rational numbers. Also, what is the range of $f$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sure. thanks for help.

Comment: @MonadNewb I know in detail about rational numbers. Cannot agree with you.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi Your question doesn't indicate much about what you already know. Please edit your question to include some of your thoughts about how you go about solving this problem.

Comment: (a) What happens when N = 0? (b) You want to define $f(a/b) = f(a) - f(b)$, for $a$ and $b$ integers, but you will run into trouble doing this with your definition: try to work out $f(-1/1)$ and $f(1/-1)$ (which should of course be the same thing), for example.

Comment: @MonadNewb not sure if I understand you correct. What I know is what rationals are and what properties they have starting with the very elementar that comes from German "Quotient", I can write here a long story then up to p-adic number and adele if you like. But I am only passively knowledgeable in abstract algebra and not certain how to "formulate" precisely such an expansion. Hope that helps you.

Comment: @Billy thanks. for (a) there is indeed a singularity that for the moemnt I think I can radically exclude $0$ (b) thanks, yes I started already this direction but was not certain about correctness of my formalism.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi Typically in Abstract Algebra, rational numbers are formulated as equivalence classes on pairs of integers. You should be able to use the properties of these equivalence classes and of logarithms and your $f$ which is already extended to the integers to further extend $f$ to the rationals. I haven't thought it all the way through because I want to leave that as an exercise for you. As far as I can tell, this seems like a promising approach.

Comment: @Billy Or in general if $a/b=c/d$, you need to show that $f(a/b)=f(c/d)$ for the chosen definition of $f$.

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi: I think you are being criticised for the informality of your formalism. Indeed, I'm not even quite sure what you are using the word "formalism" to mean. You are writing down *formulas*, but they are sloppy and imprecise, and it's not clear why you're choosing to write them down as you are. Wikipedia probably has a good page on the logarithm function; it is only 'nicely' behaved on the *positive reals*, and anywhere else you're going to get nasty things happening like my (b) above. (Also, $f((-1)^2) \neq 2f(-1)$, and so on.)

Comment: @MonadNewb, yes but as Billy rightly brought up yet I get just nasty things. Thanks for your hints.

Comment: If you need further help, edit your original question to show what you have learned so far. In particular, give your definition of $f$ extended to the rationals and show what "nasty things" come out of it. There are people here that are willing to help if you show some effort.

Comment: Oh, and look at the definition of $f$ for negative values. It is undefined at $N=-1$. You should probably use $log |N|$ when $N<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's modify the function from the OP:

$$f(n) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \log n & \quad \text{if $n>0 \qquad; n \in \Bbb Z$}\\
    \log |n| + \Bbb i\pi & \quad \text{if $n<0$}
  \end{array} \right.$$

I suggest that you look at

$$g(\frac{p}{q}) = f(p) - f(q)$$

Now you need to show that $g(\frac{a}{1})=f(a)$ and that whenever $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$ then $g(\frac{a}{b})=g(\frac{c}{d})$.

Comment: Perhaps this might be start: $$f(n) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    \log (\alpha\;n)-\log(\alpha) & \quad \text{if $n>0 \qquad;\; n \in \Bbb Q,\;\alpha\in\Bbb N$ }\\
    \log|\alpha\, n|-\log\alpha + \Bbb i\pi & \quad \text{if $n<0$}
  \end{array} \right.$$

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi What's $\alpha$? Is this a fixed number. If so, how do you chooose it? Does it depend on $n$? If so, how?

Comment: thanks having a look forwrad. $\alpha$ is a positive integer, one could possibly take it this way: Let $f(n)=\log(n)$ with $n \in \Bbb Q$ and $n>0$ then there exists an $\alpha \in \Bbb N$ such that $f(n)=\log(\alpha n)-\log(\alpha)$. (similar for $n<0$). Not sure if that works, I try to work forward a solution...

Comment: I suspect that $\alpha$ is just the denominator of $n$, which means your formulation *should* be equivalent to mine. I prefer the way I have done it because it makes it clear the $q$ is the denominator.